# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Profile'

Tags: python, django, model

## Problem:

I'm trying to get the latest value from my model called `Profile`. But I've encountered a problem, when I try to save it to a variable as a float value I get this error `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Profile'`. I need this so, I can make calculations with the datas.

## Models.py file:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
      weight = models.FloatField()
      height = models.FloatField()
      bmi = models.FloatField(null=True)
      date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
      user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.user.username
```

## Views.py file (relevant parts):

```
    weight = float(Profile.objects.latest('weight'))
    height = float(Profile.objects.latest('height'))
    bmi = (weight/(height**2))
```

I searched up this error code here, but I didn't find any, where ppl wanted to convert from `obj` to `float`

Comment: It does return whole Profile instance so you should access its property .weight etc.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression:

```
Profile.objects.latest('weight')
```

Does *not* return a float value, it returns the `Profile` with the *highest* `weight`. But not the weight itself.

You can however easily obtain both values by [**`.aggregate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate):

```
from django.db.models import Max

result = Profile.objects.aggregate(
    max_weight=Max('weight'),
    max_height=Max('height')
)

weight = result['max_weight']
height = result['max_height']

bmi = weight / (height * height)
```

Note that this *not* per se the person with the largest bmi. It will simply look for the largest weight and height of all `Profile`s. (Very) likely the data will originate from two *different* `Profile`s.

If you want to calculate the BMI of a `Profile`, you can use:

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=my_pk)

bmi = profile.weight / (profile.height * profile.height)
```

You can obtain the `Profile` with the largest primary key `pk`:

```
profile = Profile.objects.latest('pk')

bmi = profile.weight / (profile.height * profile.height)
```

but that is not per se the latest added object.

Comment: @Monard: well there is no such thing as a *latest* value. A database can return records in every possible order. You can retrieve the `Profile` with the largest `pk`, with the last code snippet. It is however better to add a timestamp with the creation date, since that is the only reliable way to retrieve the latest object.

Comment: Thanks for your help!